# creating an object with user's selections in UI, and displaying it back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some dropdown and checkbox items on the front end.

I have an object that collects all the selections made by the user. For example:

```
Object myObject = new object();
myObject.Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(DropDown1.SelectedValue);
myObject.Value2 = Convert.ToInt32(CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue)
```

I want to be able to store one instance of the object on the "submit" button click and give the user options to create more instances, by changing selections.

Then, I would want to display each object they create in a grid below. How can i do this in an elegant fashion?

I was thinking of creating an arraylist of my object, but how would I display that data back in a gridview or something to that effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a datatable and add rows into datatable and assign as datasource to gridview.
you can use this...

```
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

    if (ViewState["dtbl"] == null)
    {
        DataColumn PID = new DataColumn();//Adding column When adding item first time
        dtbl.Columns.Add(PID);
        DataColumn PName = new DataColumn();
        dtbl.Columns.Add(PName);
    }
    else
    {
        dtbl = (DataTable)ViewState["dtbl"];
    }

    DataRow dr = dtbl.NewRow();
    dr["PID"] = "1";
    dr["PName"] = "product Name";
    dtbl.Rows.Add(dr);
    ViewState.Add("dtbl", dtbl);

    yourGridView.DataSource = dtbl.DefaultView;
    yourGridView.DataBind();
```